# Create cache for mobile using ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, tilecache

I want to use tile map service ( cache map) in a mobile project . I'm using ArcGIS SDK for android as a API and the basemap is ArcGIS Tile map.The mobile operating systems of end users are android and The property of cache service is as below :

DPI :96

Tile height and width : 256 * 256

Tile format : JPG

storage format : compact

The cache scales are based on google map scales ( 20 zoom level)

maximum resolution of my system is 1920 * 1080

The problem is that the quality of map in mobile device get low .

How can i show the high quality map in my project ?

Which API's or SDK  do you recommend instead of Arcgis sdk for android ?

Comment: Increasing DPI of the JPG definitely improves image quality. But ArcGIS gets pretty fidgetty when you alter the DPI...

Comment: What are you using the google maps api for? Do you need it if you are using the ESRI android SDK and ESRI cached map services?

Comment: @Dowlers i'm sorry.i'm using ArcGIS SDK for android. i edited my question .

Answer (score 1):

### If you are creating your own cache:

1. Increase the jpeg compression ratio when generating the cache, the default is 75.

Or

2. Change the jpeg format to png32. This will result in a larger cache and bigger tiles but it will also improve quality

### If you are using an ArcGIS online tiled map service

Make sure that your application only allows zooming to the cached scales. The standard scales are the same for ESRI, Bing and Google. The largest scale is 1:1028 (I think). If your app allows users to zoom to scales other that these the tiles become blurry. The map [resamples](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/03/18/welcome-to-resampling/) the tiles allowing zooming in further but blurring the .jpgs.